# How to update emacs on MS Windows?

Tags: microsoft-windows, upgrade

I have installed emacs 2-3 years ago. The version I'm using now is `25.2.1`. I want to update it to the latest version, which is `27.1`. I uninstalled it and then installed again to no avail, it is the same old version. I have googled it, read a few sites, even came over [StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29717203/emacs-24-3-on-windows-how-to-upgrade-to-the-most-recent-version). None of those sources was helpful. Also, when installing it, I do it so via `MSYS`. That `MSYS` also shows `MinGW` things when it installs. I also looked at `path` in Environment variables in MS Windows Settings. I don't understand those things; neither `path` nor `MSYS` or `MinGW` is comprehensible for an amateur like me. So, can you help me and other future amateurs who will look here for help?

How can I upgrade to latest emacs on Windows?

I'm using Windows 10 64-bit. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can download an MS Windows binary for the latest Emacs release (27.1) here:

https://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/emacs/windows/emacs-27/

It sounds like you probably want one of the "64" ones. I use this one:

- emacs-27-deps-mingw-w64-src.zip

But do read the README first: README-windows-binaries.